# В чем смысл некоторых аннотаций в Doctrine?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, doctrine2

Работаю над своим небольшим проектом, использую Laravel и Doctrine как основную ORM. Doctrine была выбрана только с целью получить опыт работы с ней. Для миграций, принял решение использовать встроенные в laravel средства.

Собственно вопрос: когда определяешь `Entity`, обязательно ли указывать опции в аннотациях, которые были заданы в миграциях(тип, длины строки, nullable ...)?
Как я понял: эти опции используются только при генерации таблиц. Или все же, doctrine как-то контролирует целостность в runtim'e?

Answer (score 0):

Она контроллирует, допустим у вас есть модель `User` с полем `$name`, ассертами указано, что оно не должно быть пустым и представляет собой строку. Теперь при попытке записать туда пустую строку или запихнуть массив, вы получите `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception`, которое можно перехватить и выдать красивую ошибку о неверных данных

Comment: Хоть один пример?

Comment: @svgrafov ага, сейчас для демонстрации базовых вещей из документации брошу работу и начну писать пример. А давайте вариант лучше - у меня как раз рабочий проект на доктрине, может плюнем на NDA и солью сюда всё?

Comment: @СашаБоричевский, не стоит горячится - если у вас нет времени/возможности показать пример - это не страшно. Хотя с примером, конечно, ответ будет лучше

Comment: Ответ вообще кажется неверным, но мне, конечно, лень уточнять.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вопрос общий, ответ такой же. Максимум - можно еще ссылку на документацию дать. В любом случае доктрина именно с помощью аннотаций понимает, можно ли писать данные определенного типа в поле и как я выше расписал - можно еще ко всему прочему для валидации покрыть всё ассертами. Просто тупо не понимаю какой тут пример можно написать? Все есть в документации. Мой ответ - всего лишь компиляция того, что там расписано на нескольких страницах, плюс опыт